# Will a Win32 application run on window 7 and windows 8/8.1 as well?

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-runtime, window, user32

I want to develop a window application that will have capability to **read properties of another window application** eg. text boxes, options, buttons, title bar and more. My application would use multithreading as separate thread is always required to activate targetted window.

So, I have found that I should start with win32 API that is common to many windows operating systems but my concern is if the win32 API is supported on Window 7 and Window 8 or 8.1 that uses winRT API.
I actually want my application to run on all Windows platforms.

I have a lot of confusion between these APIs. Please help me understand how I could develop my application.

Comment: This is far too broad. Also, unless you already know the various frameworks well, you are bound to make lots of wrong decisions. I don't think you are ready to write this app yet.

Comment: *"My application would use multithreading as separate thread is always required to activate targetted window."* It sounds like you do not have even the slightest clue, what you are doing. Start with [theForger's Win32 API Tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/), and build a **solid** foundation before moving on.

Answer (score 0):

Win32 has been and continues to be available on all versions of Windows (with small exceptions like Windows RT that does not allow installation of desktop applications). There have been additions to the API between 7, 8, and 8.1, and there are probably also new APIs in Windows 10. In short, Win32 remains a core API in Windows. The WinRT API was build as an addition to Win32, primarily for Store apps but not exclusively. WinRT itself uses Win32, and a Win32 application can use both Win32 and WinRT APIs. Furthermore, desktop applications build with .NET technologies like Windows Presentation Foundation can access Win32 APIs as well.

In short, Win32 is the broadest common denominator for Windows and is a good choice for the kind of utility application you're thinking about.

Comment: Not true. ARM-based Windows RT systems do not expose the Windows API. You cannot run desktop applications on ARM-based Microsoft Surface devices, for example.